# What do you call the enclosed outdoor area inside an apt?

Tags: names

It's an outside area about 1.5m square that can be entered from inside the apartment through a window-like entetance. It's filled with garbage from apartments in the higher floors.

I want to say skylight but I'm not sure.

What do you call it?

Comment: This does not describe "skylight" in my dictionary.

Comment: Is it the landing of a fire escape?

Comment: In New York City, that's an *air shaft*, required by old zoning laws to provide "fresh air" but no view. It was a vertical hole inside the apartment building, not inside the apartments.

Comment: Is it supposed to be a place for garbage, like in bags for pick up? Or does it look like people are just being messy? What country is this in? You say it is 'outside' but having a skylight (a plastic or glass cover) makes it not outside. Does it have a cover (can it rain o the garbage)? Can it be accessed on the ground floor? Do you have an image you can link to? So many questions.

Comment: Such a space might be called an "interior courtyard", although, as other commenters have mentioned, your meaning isn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry, I take that back . . . 1.5 square meters seems much too small for a courtyard.

Comment: If the space is at the bottom of a shaft with windows in the walls at all the other levels then it is a [light well](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightwell) also known, as @YosefBaskin says, as an "air shaft". It is rather small at 1.5m square so I assume that the block is not very high (or at least that the lower floors are occupied by commercial premises) but the idea is that natural light and fresh air are supplied to the apartments. The garbage should not really be there, perhaps it has accumulated over a long period having been dropped accidentally, or even blown in from the top.

Comment: Related: [What's the word for an unused, enclosed space between two apartment buildings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/545207).

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. What is described in the body of the question seems to be, as pointed out by other commentators, the bottom of a lightwell (air shaft), but such an area is not normally regarded as **inside** the ground-floor apartment. The fact that it can be accessed from that apartment only 'through a window-like entrance' should be taken as an indication that it is not meant to be accessed by the occupants of that apartment at all.